# The package conflicts with an existing package

Tags: android

I have installed an app from Amazon app store and now I have updated the app version in IDE and want it to replace the existing one in the device. But it is showing "App not installed." "The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name". I have checked its .jks file too, I am using the old one to generate the signed apk.

Comment: Ok, what is the question? This dialog showed you can accept?

Comment: Hi Canato, As I have written above that I want to replace the existing app in my device with this updated version apk..

Comment: ok, you tried to uninstall and install the new one?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to uninstall the old one

Comment: You want to keep both in your device?

Comment: No, I want it to replace the old one like if we update an app from app store then it never shows this kind messages.

Comment: Ok, on this message you can accept or only deny?

Comment: It shows only one option i.e. Done

Comment: This app is your app or from another source?

Comment: This is my app...But now I want to upload its updated version but before that just wanted to check that is it giving option of update or not?

Comment: OK, normally this happens because you installed the app direct from Android Studio and try to update from another store.  Are you 100% sure that you only download from amazon and wanna to update from the same source (amazon)?

Because your message is "App not installed..." what make me understand that you are trying to install the app, not update. If the app come from the same store you will not try to installed, but update

Comment: No Actually I downloaded app from amazon and now I am updating it from device storage.

Comment: So this error will always happen, is only let you update if you get from the same source

Comment: But I try same for another app it was working. Only different was I downloaded it from Google play store. And can able to update from device storage.

Comment: So sorry, I cannot help more far than that, hope someone has your answer XD

Comment: Ok Canato, thnaks

Comment: @Canato "is only let you update if you get from the same source" Are there any official documentation stating this?